# telerik:RadSlider - need a single drag slider instead of 2-drag slider

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I m using the telerik:RadSlider in my project and its come up fine except it has a 2-drag slider and i only want a 1 drag slider - does anyone know how to get rid of the second one? here's my code:

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />
                        <telerik:RadSlider id ="rdSlider" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="450"
                                Height="50" MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue="50" LargeChange="10" TrackPosition="BottomRight"
                                ItemType="Tick" IsSelectionRangeEnabled="true" SelectionStart="10" SelectionEnd="30" Skin="Default" DragText="Select Premium" >

                        </telerik:RadSlider>
```

Also does anyone know how to make the slider (but not the bar) a different colour such as red?

Many thanks

Comment: Hi just changed the IsSelectionRangeEnabled="true" to "false" and it has become single!

Comment: if anyone still know how to change the colour of the drag slider it would be appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `IsSelectionRangeEnabled` property to False.

For more information see: [Slider Handles](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/slider-handles.html)

For the color of the slider, AFAIK you will need to create a custom skin. See: [Creating a custom skin](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/slider-appearance-custom-skin.html)